# Azure Functions PowerShell - Accessing Timestamp value from Azure Storage Table

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I am building a timer-triggered Azure Function that uses a PowerShell script. For input binding, there is Azure Table Storage. In order to use newly added values in my script, I was hoping to make use of the automatic `Timestamp` value that gets generated on each value addition to the table. However, the Timestamp is rendered empty when I run the function. The values are present in the table though.

My test code -

```
# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Timer, $inputTable)

$newValues = $inputTable.GetEnumerator()
$newValues | ForEach-Object {
    Write-host $_.Timestamp
}
```

Output when `Write-host $_.Timestamp`

```
2022-06-17T07:16:55.538 [Information] OUTPUT:
2022-06-17T07:16:55.614 [Information] INFORMATION:
2022-06-17T07:16:55.616 [Information] INFORMATION:
2022-06-17T07:16:55.621 [Information] INFORMATION:
```

Output for any other value Eg. `Write-host $_.PartitionKey`  -

```
2022-06-17T07:17:34.230 [Information] OUTPUT:
2022-06-17T07:17:34.310 [Information] INFORMATION: partition1
2022-06-17T07:17:34.312 [Information] INFORMATION: partition1
2022-06-17T07:17:34.318 [Information] INFORMATION: partition1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the Table Storage input binding then I don't think the TimeStamp is present in the returned data.

#### Example

I have a function which has HTTP Input Binding and Table Storage Input Binding to lookup a list of users for table storage when invoked.

##### Table Storage

[image]

**function.json**

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "Request",
      "methods": [
        "get"
      ],
      "route": "get/user"
    },
    {
      "name": "PersonEntity",
      "type": "table",
      "tableName": "users",
      "connection": "MyStorageConnectionAppSetting",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "Response"
    }
  ]
}
```

**run.ps1**

When I trigger the function it returns all users but the TimeStamp property is not returned from table storage. I don't think there's a way to retrieve this using the input binding.

##### Debugging Output

[image]

Also looks like someone logged an issue here:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-nodejs-worker/issues/320

And this is the same as with Python and NodeJs bindings so not unique to PowerShell.

You could use the AzTable module that was linked in the other answer or there is another module (AzBobbyTables) in the PowerShell Gallery which is newer and written in C# and is supposed to be much more performant:

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzBobbyTables/2.0.0

https://twitter.com/PalmEmanuel/status/1462818044959461382

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the **[Get-AzTableRow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-how-to-use-powershell#retrieve-all-entities)** in your azure function, you will not **give the time stamp**.

The **Get-AzTableRow** will return the ***table columns*** and ***Partition*** and ***RowKey***.

If you are trying to get the **timestamp** you have to **convert** that into **string**. likes below

```bash
Type - 1
[String]$_.Timestamp

# or 
Type - 2
$_.Timestamp.toString("s")
```

I have added the same thing in your code.

```bash
$newValues | ForEach-Object {
    Write-host $_.Timestamp.toString("s")
}
```